# Prove or disprove that the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-1)$ is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

> Prove or disprove  that the ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-1)$ is an
>   integral domain.

It is easy to see that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f)=\{P+(f): \deg(P)<\deg(f)\}$. If $\deg(P) \geq \deg(f)$, there exists $q,r \in \mathbb{Z}[x]$ such that $P=qf+r$ with $r=0$ or $\deg(r)< \deg(f) \implies P+(f)=qf+r+(f)=r+(f)$. So $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f) = \{0,1, x, (x-1), (x+1)\}$. But $(x-1)(x+1)= x^2-1 \equiv 0 \mod (x^2-1)$.

**Conclusion :** Our ring is not an integral domain.

**Question :** Am I right? Otherwise, is anyone could help me on the ambiguity of this problem?

Comment: Yes, if $f$ is not irreducible, then $(f)$ is not a prime ideal, and $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f)$ is not an integral domain (equivalent to $(f)$ being a prime ideal).

Comment: I don't understand why $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(f)$ is $\{0,1, x, (x-1), (x+1)\}$ and not $\{ax+b\} \ \ a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Would you be able to prove it?

Comment: $x+1$ is a divisor of zero, hence our ring is not an integral domain. Isn't it trivial?

Answer (score 1):

You are making it hard on yourself. To show that the quotient ring is not an integral domain, you need only find *any* zero divisor. You are not correct in your description of what $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-1)$ is as a ring but you have correctly pulled out the necessary fact: $\overline{x+1},\overline{x-1} \in \mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-1)$ and $\overline{x-1} \cdot \overline{x+1}=\overline{x^2-1}$ which is $\overline{0}$ in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-1)$ but neither $\overline{x-1},\overline{x+1}$ are zero.

What is $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-1)$ really? As you said for any polynomial in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, say $p(x)$, we can use division to express $p(x)$ as $p(x)=q(x)(x^2-1)+r(x)$, where $\deg r(x)<2$ (that is, $\deg r(x)$ is $0$ or $1$). Then in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-1)$, $\overline{p(x)}=\overline{q(x)(x^2-1)+r(x)}=\overline{q(x)(x^2-1)}+\overline{r(x)}=\overline{r(x)}$. So all nonzero elements in $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-1)$ (those which aren't multiples of $x^2-1$, i.e. where $r(x)=0$) are any nonzero elements in $\mathbb{Z}[x]$ of degree $1$ or $0$. Then as a set, $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x^2-1)=\{ax+b\;|\;a,b \in \mathbb{Z}\}$.